# How to show that I is a Prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> I want to show that $ I= (x_2 ^ 2 - x_1 ^2 - x_1 ^3) $ is a prime ideal.

I know that I should show that the quotient of the $K[x_1, x_2]/ I$ is an integral domain. I know that all the powers of the $x_1$ are 1 or 2 in this quotient, but I don't know what should I have to do. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: I think it would be easier to show that the polynomial in question is irreducible.

Comment: Sorry , I edited the post, it didn't sound easy for me to showing its irreducibility.

Comment: $K$ is a field?

Comment: yes, an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x_2^2 - x_1^2 - x_1^3$ as a polynomial in $k[x_1][x_2]$. Since $-x_1^2 - x_1^3 = -x_1^2(x_1 + 1) \in (x_1 + 1)$ and $(x_1 + 1)$ is prime in $k[x_1]$, [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) says $x_2^2 - x_1^2 - x_1^3$ is irreducible. Thus, the corresponding ideal is prime.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know generalized Eisenstein's criterion and used it as you said and it solved. Thanks!